# Can I insert the version number in the info file of a module for internal use?

Tags: 8

The documentation on the creation of custom modules says,

```
# Note: do not add the 'version' or 'project' properties yourself.
# They will be added automatically by the packager on drupal.org.
```

so I never put a version number in my module. But then I add difficulties writing database update scripts, I never managed to get an `N` in `hook_update_N()` that the update would recognize.

Also, my module *really* doesn't have any utility outside of my organization, since it has very specific domain requirements; therefore it is not, and never will, be released as a contributed module.

So, can I use a version number in my info file, and use it to generate the name of the update function? And if I insert it in an update of my module, will it be correctly managed?

Comment: `hook_update_N` is unrelated to any version string in the info file - if you’re having trouble with those hooks, concentrate on that issue; adding a version, while yes of course you can do, and it won’t break anything, won’t affect update hooks. What it _may_ do, is give you a red/yellow item in the available updates list, as I think the updater will check d.org for versions of the module if `version` is set

Answer (score 4):

If you host your module outside of drupal.org, including a private Git repository, or a local computer from which the module is copied on the site, you can set the `version` key in the .info.yml file for the module.

If the module updates are handled differently, the module could also implement [`hook_update_projects_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21update.api.php/function/hook_update_projects_alter/8.9.x) to tell the Update Manager not to check for that module updates, for example implementing the code shown in the documentation.

```php
function mymodule_update_projects_alter(&$projects) {
  // Hide a site-specific module from the list.
  unset($projects['site_specific_module']);
}
```

As for the number *N* used in `hook_update_N()`, that number isn't related to the module version. It's just a progressive number, used from Drupal to verify which `hook_update_N()` implementation has been already run. [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.9.x) explains the convention for the four digits used for N.

- 1 or 2 digits for Drupal core compatibility (for example, 8 for compatibility with Drupal 8, 10 for compatibility with Drupal 10)
- 1 digit for your module's major release version (for example 1 for the 8.x-1.3 release)
- 2 digits for a counting number, starting from *01*

To use an existing project as example, the [pathauto.install file for the release 8.x-1.11](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/blob/8.x-1.1/pathauto.install) defines, as last update hook `pathauto_update_8106()`; the [same file for the release 8.x-1.5](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/blob/8.x-1.5/pathauto.install) has `pathauto_update_8107()` as last update hook, which is the latest update hook also for [the release 8.x-1.8](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/blob/8.x-1.8/pathauto.install).

Note that the digit for the major version release isn't sufficient to describe the version release (which would include also the minor version), but it's not sufficient also for a major version that is higher than 9.
Note also that Drupal core won't report any error whether (for example) a 8.x-2.3 release contains `mymodule_update_8133()` as update hook. What described is a convention for which only the Drupal compatibility digit is required.